# Is there a concise alternative to this cascaded if / elseif / else construct in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax, if-statement

I am working on a project which requires making discrete values out of numeric quantities all over the place. At present I'm using cascaded if / elseif / else constructs, for example:

```
    if M > 6
        evidence{2} = 3;
    elseif M > 2
        evidence{2} = 2;
    else
        evidence{2} = 1;
    end
```

I want to replace this with a more maintainable (and concise) syntax, but before I come up with my own idiom I would like to know if there is already a convenient function or syntax available in MATLAB. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on what forms the conditions can take.

Comment: What's the problem with the `if` statements? It's readable and maintainable.

Comment: The `if` statements get unwieldy when your functions contain scores of them. And they also are not very convenient when you want to experiment with changing the number of categories.

Comment: Have you considered the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
evidence{2} = sum( M > [-inf 2 6] )
```

Basically, you are searching for the interval in which M lies: (-inf,2], (2,6], (6,+inf)

So even if your values were not 1/2/3, you could then map the range index found to some other values...

Answer (score 3):

```
evidence{2} = 1 + (M > 2) + (M > 6);
```

but in my opinion, it is less maintainable. Yours is better.

Comment: You'll need parenthesis around the logical quantities: `1+(M>2)+(M>6)` to specify the precedence.